# Understanding ７７の海岸のうち６０％で、

Tags: reading-comprehension

> そして、調べた**７７の海岸のうち６０％で**、砂が全部なくなる可能性があることがわかりました。
>   In 60% of the 77 coasts investigated, it is understood that there is a possibility that all the sand will be lost.

I'm a bit confused by the 調べた７７の海岸のうち６０％で part. I'm assuming it means "in 60% of the 77 coasts investigated", but I'm uncomfortable with the lack of particle between うち and 60%. How do the following differ:

> ７７の海岸のうち６０％で
>   ７７の海岸のうちの６０％で  this one feels ungrammatical to me
>   ７７の海岸の６０％で

Maybe I'm trying to join ７７の海岸のうち and 60% into a single phrase when I shouldn't. Perhaps the correct answer is "Among the 77 coasts investigated, in 60% of them ...". Could I write ７７の海岸のうち、それの６０％で with the same meaning as the original?

Comment: this is beyond my conversational level of Japanese, but this JSE post may be relevant:
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21570/why-is-%e3%81%a7-in-%e4%b8%89%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e3%81%86%e3%81%a1%e3%81%a7%e4%b8%80%e7%95%aa-omissible-but-%e3%81%a7-in-%e3%81%93%e3%81%93%e3%81%a7%e5%be%85%e3%81%a4-not
and this website lists examples of other のうち patterns:
https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%AE%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - 77の海岸のうち60%で
> - 77の海岸のうちの60%で
> - 77の海岸の60%で

These all mean the same thing, and they are interchangeable. うち is basically a noun, but it can form an adverbial phrase or clause without another particle, just as 時, 中 can 場合 can do so.

From 明鏡国語辞典:

> #### うち
>
> ⑩㋑ 問題とする数値がある範囲の中から選ばれたことを表す。
>   「仲間のうち二人が合格した」「定価のうち（の）二割を内金として払う」「三人残ったうちの一人が犯人だ」

うち is often optional, but it can remove an ambiguity from a sentence. For example, 友達の2人 means either "the two friends (mentioned in the conversation)" or "two of the (many) friends" depending on the context. 友達のうちの2人 only means the latter.